# How to list all the objects tagged to a role in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How to list all the objects and privileges  tagged to a role in Oracle.
I gave exeute permission of an object to one role. I want to list all the objects tagged to the role

Answer (score 1):

Query `ROLE_TAB_PRIVS`; for example:

```
SQL> grant select on emp to my_role;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select, update on dept to my_role;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select * from role_tab_privs;

ROLE    OWNER TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM PRIVILEGE    GRA
------- ----- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---
MY_ROLE SCOTT DEPT                  UPDATE       NO
MY_ROLE SCOTT DEPT                  SELECT       NO
MY_ROLE SCOTT EMP                   SELECT       NO

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @littlefoot said, ROLE_TAB_PRIVS will show you what is granted directly to a role.  But if you need to see what is granted to a role that is granted to a role (recursive roles) you need to see one of two scripts written by Pete Finnigan.  To see everything granted to a role, recurseively, see http://www.petefinnigan.com/find_all_privs.sql. For other variations, just look over what is available at http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm